# How to resize images in a folder and save it to another folder in Python?

Tags: image, resize

I have a folder of images. I resize each image in this folder and want to save the resized image to a different folder. The following is my code:

```
import glob
import os

new_folder = '/new/folder/of/images/'
for file in [x for x in glob.glob('/existing/folder/of/images/*.jpg')]:
        im = Image.open(file)
        img = im.convert('RGB')
        new_img = img.resize((500,500))
        new_img.save(os.path.join(new_folder, file +'_resized'+'.jpg'), 'JPEG', optimize=True)
```

The images get resized. However, the resized images are being saved in the same folder as the original images, and not in the new_folder as I want.  Is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code
`

```
from PIL import Image
import os


def scale(naziv,h,w):
    image = Image.open(naziv)
    resized = image.resize((w, h))
    i=naziv.split('\\')
    name=i[-1].split('.')
    print(name[0])
    resized.save('C:\\Path\\Of\\New\\File\\'+name[0]+'-copy.jpg')# Add to new file image u wont to save


def main():

    dir_path = "C:\\Put\\File\\Path\\Here" #file u want o take pictures from
    res = []

    os.mkdir("C:\\Make\\new\\File\\Here",0o666)#write the full path of new file(with name of file)

    for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
        # check if the current path is a file
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
            res.append(path)
            scale(dir_path+"\\"+path,321,208) 
   
    

main()
```

`